# how to add global keyevent JComponent

Tags: java, swing, keylistener, key-bindings, jdialog

anyone know how to add Component action key default ?

i hear about UImanager actionMap, but im not sure
i have 3 combo box and 2 text field and 1 table
its very wasting time to add each component a key listener press ESC to dispose Dialog
like

```
     KeyAdapter key=new KeyAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            int x=JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "EXIT APP ?", null, JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
            if(x==JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
            {
                dialog.setVisible(false);
                dialog.dispose();
            }
        }            
    };
    combo1.addKeyListener(key);
    combo2.addKeyListener(key);
    combo3.addKeyListener(key);
    table.addKeyListener(key);
    dialog.addKeyListener(key);
    text1.addKeyListener(key);
    text2.addKeyListener(key);
```

any solution to make default key if i press ESC from any Component JDialog will dispose ?

Comment: Just add a key bind to the JDialog content pane. See [How to use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html). I don't understand why you need to add one to all the compoents

Comment: @peeskillet `Just add a key bind to the JDialog content pane` - yes I found that out the hard way. I was originally adding the bindings to the root pane which caused me grief. Where was this answer last night when I need it :)

Answer (score 1):

I was just playing with code to do this last night. So you get lucky with some spoon fed code.

Don't forget to read the Key Bindings tutorial so you understand the solution.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;

/**
**  This class will close a JDialog (or a window) when the Escape key is used.
*/
public class EscapeAction extends AbstractAction
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        Component c = KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().getFocusOwner();
        SwingUtilities.windowForComponent(c).dispose();
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JDialog dialog = new JDialog();

        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        dialog.setJMenuBar( menuBar );

        JMenu menu = new JMenu( "File" );
        menuBar.add( menu );
        menu.add( new JMenuItem("FileMenuA") );
        JMenu subMenu = new JMenu( "SubFileMenu" );
        menu.add( subMenu );
        subMenu.add( new JMenuItem("SubFileMenuA") );

        menu.add( new JMenuItem("FileMenuB") );
        menu.add( new JMenuItem("FileMenuC") );

        JPopupMenu popup = new JPopupMenu();
        popup.add( new JMenuItem("SubMenuA") );
        popup.add( new JMenuItem("SubMenuB") );
        popup.add( new JMenuItem("SubMenuC") );
        popup.add( new JMenuItem("SubMenuD") );

        String[] items = { "Select Item", "Color", "Shape", "Fruit" };
        JComboBox<String> comboBox = new JComboBox<String>( items );
        dialog.add(comboBox, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        JTextField textField = new JTextField("Right Click For Popup");
        textField.setComponentPopupMenu(popup);
        dialog.add(textField);

        dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation( JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE );
        dialog.setSize(200, 200);
        dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        dialog.setVisible( true );

        //  Add the Key Bindings to the content pane for the EscapeAction

        JPanel contentPane = (JPanel)dialog.getContentPane();
        String escapeText = "ESCAPE";
        KeyStroke escapeKeyStroke = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(escapeText);
        contentPane.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(escapeKeyStroke, escapeText);
        contentPane.getActionMap().put(escapeText, new EscapeAction());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks your solution ,i already tested, but the another problem is key binding wont work if already consume() and keylistener still work event use consume()

Comment: No idea what you are talking about. None of the code posted uses consume. Anyway you should NOT be using a KeyListener. There is no need to use a KeyListener for any part of this solution. Swing was designed to be used with Key Bindings.